# passing a temporary table into another stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i would like to do this:

```
DECLARE @TmpTable TABLE = select * from someTable where someTable.Column1='BLAH'
```

i need `@TmpTable` to be a subset of `someTable` and i don't want to implicitly declare a structure with fields for `@TmpTable`, rather i want it to be dynamically created from someTable.

is this possible?

thanks so much for you help and guidance!

i've taken the suggestion to try the temporary table. however, i am getting the error:

```
  The table #SubSet does not exist in the database
```

here's the code:

```
DECLARE @StartDT DATE
DECLARE @MinDOS DATE
SELECT @MinDOS = MIN(dos) FROM accn_demographics
SELECT @StartDT = 
    CAST(CAST(datepart(YYYY,@MinDOS) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(datepart(mm,@MinDOS) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST('01' AS varchar) AS DATETIME)
DECLARE @FileLocation VARCHAR(50)
DROP TABLE #SubSet
WHILE @StartDT < '20110901'
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
        INTO #SubSet
    FROM ViewAccountDetail
    WHERE datepart(yyyy,ViewAccountDetail.DOS) = datepart(yyyy,@StartDT)
        AND datepart(mm,ViewAccountDetail.DOS) = datepart(mm,@StartDT)
    SET @FileLocation='C:\test\'+'ViewAccountDetail'+cast(@StartDT as varchar)+'.csv'
    EXEC BCP_Text_File #SubSet, @FileLocation       
    SET @StartDT = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@StartDT)

    DROP TABLE #SubSet
END
```

Comment: use Temporally tables
`select * into #Temp from someTable where someTable.Column1='BLAH'`
Then you can use #Temp for make as @TmpTable

Comment: can you please show me how i can do this?

Comment: sorry, was editing haha. You don't need to declare anything, you just do the insert

Comment: he's not using mysql, so no that won't work so well.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to do it in a temporary table? It is possible, but I am wondering that unless you need it for performance purposes, could a normal SELECT INTO to a normal table not work for you?

Comment: @Arran absolutely, can you show me what that would look like?

Comment: @Arran can you please check the update, i tried to do with temporary tables

Comment: You're getting the error because you have a DROP TABLE #SubSet directly above the while loop, but the table is made *in* the while loop and doesn't exist there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what i did!

```
DECLARE @StartDT DATE 
DECLARE @MinDOS DATE 
SELECT @MinDOS = MIN(dos) FROM accn_demographics 
SELECT @StartDT = 
CAST(CAST(datepart(YYYY,@MinDOS) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(datepart(mm,@MinDOS) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST('01' AS varchar) AS DATETIME) 
DECLARE @FileLocation VARCHAR(50) 
DROP TABLE #SubSet 
WHILE @StartDT < '20110901' 
BEGIN 
SELECT * 
INTO SubSet 
FROM ViewTransactionDetails 
WHERE datepart(yyyy,ViewTransactionDetails.DOS) = datepart(yyyy,@StartDT) 
AND datepart(mm,ViewTransactionDetails.DOS) = datepart(mm,@StartDT) 
SET @FileLocation='C:\test\'+'ViewTransactionDetails'+cast(@StartDT as varchar)+'.csv' 
EXEC BCP_Text_File SubSet, @FileLocation    
SET @StartDT = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@StartDT) 

DROP TABLE SubSet 
END
```

thank you everyone for your extraordinary help!

i went with a permanent table and just keep dropping it!

Answer (score 5):

```
select * 
into #temptable
from someTable 
where someTable.Column1='BLAH'
```

just change "@" to "#" ;)  You can also use CTE for this as well. [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: great! could i do select * 
into #temptable
from '@'someTable 
where '@'someTable.Column1='BLAH' ??? since '@'someTable is a variable

Comment: i had to put the at sign in ' ' because stackoverflow didnt like it

Comment: Look into CTE to see if that's more appropriate for what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH A
AS
(
    select * from someTable where someTable.Column1='BLAH'
)
```

where `A` is the Alias of your "temporary table". After that you can select it like another normal table. Just know that you **CAN'T** make and `Order By` in the `select * from someTable where someTable.Column1='BLAH'`

Comment: thanks so much this is a great solution. i am having a slight issue

Comment: great that helps, which issue?

Comment: i am declaring the WITH inside my store procedure. and then i have a WHILE loop after that. it seems that i cannot see the WITH inside my while loop?

Comment: Yes you can see it, post your full SP to clarify your issue and also the description error that you are getting

Comment: im sorry i have made a slight change and still trying to get this work with temporary tables, can you please assist

Comment: so, you are trying to pass the table as a Parameter to another SP? o.O

Comment: and then i am getting The table #SubSet does not exist in the database

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12572/discussion-between---and-mr)